# Batching Transactions in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

As we are aware that Stripe charges 2.9% + 30 cents per credit card charge. So for every $1 transaction, Stripe takes roughly 33 cents. Is there a way to batch multiple $ 1 transactions (by the same customer) and charge them altogether?

Say we do 100 transactions of $1 each, we end up paying approx $33 to Stripe. Could it be possible to charge all the transactions at once ,in this case Stripe will only charge $2.9+ 30 cents ie $3.2?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this either by summing up the microtransactions on your end and [creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) for the total amount, or [subscribing](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) your customers to a $0 plan then [creating invoice items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) for each microtransaction. At the end of each billing period, Stripe will automatically create an invoice that includes all the items you created and charge the customer for the total amount.

You can find more information in [this support article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-microtransactions-and-will-my-fees-be-the-same).

Comment: Hi Ywain,

Thanks. Can we maybe batch multiple cards as well? 
Say if I have a store and many users do some purchases (really small amounts). Can I batch all of the transactions together to consolidate one BIG charge at the end of the day?

Comment: Hey @amty, no, a charge can only have a single payment source, so you'd have to create one charge per card.